# Making a letter head for certificate page of thesis

Tags: latex, tabular

I am trying to make a letter head to make a certificate to put in a thesis. I have posted the MWE below.

There are 2 issues I need help with

1. The cell alignment of the letterhead, is not proper. I am not sure how to correct it.
2. I need the double lines to be in red colour, I wasn't able to get it.

The final output should be something like this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuMdN.jpg)

```
\documentclass[12 pt,a4 paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1in,right=1 in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{multirow}
\fancyhf{}
  \noindent
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[.7ex]{\linewidth}{#1}}%
  \rule[.3ex]{\linewidth}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\vspace{12 mm}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{{\Large Bangalore}} & \multirow{1}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.175\linewidth]{BUB_Emblem}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{{\Large University}}\\

%\multicolumn{1}{r}{\Huge{Bangalore}} & \multirow{1}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{BUB_Emblem}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\Huge{University}}\\
 \large{Dr Vijaykumar H Doddamani} &   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Department of Physics} \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{M.Sc., M. Phil., PhD} && \multicolumn{1}{l}{Ph. Off: 080-22961471/84} \\
&&\multicolumn{1}{l}{Fax: 080-23219295}\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{\large Professor}} & & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Mobile : 9481300346} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Email: drvkd@gmail.com} & Jnanabharathi Campus  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Mobile : 9448673274} \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{profvijaykumarhd@bub.ernet.in} & Bengaluru - 560 056  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{WhatsApp :9741716744} \\
%
\end{tabular}
\vskip2mm
\vspace{2mm}
\doublerule[1pt]

\end{document}
```

With this code, This is the output I am getting.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TODvQ.jpg)

I have put in the arrows and comments in this image[arrows and comments for width alinment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZQ7I.jpg)

Comment: Your code does not compile. You must not have typesetting commands like `\noindent` in the preamble and your mysterious `\doublerule` macro is not defined.

Comment: Also an error description of "The cell alignment [...] is not proper." is not very helpful. You must tell us what result you are looking for!

Comment: I found these codes on stack exchange when searching for how to write double line in latex

Comment: Then please include the code in your question. If you ask about how to change a macro and don't show us the definition, how should be guess the code which might or might not solve your problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but please read the section about "times" in http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nag/nag.pdf

Comment: @sam I have added a image of what I need for the output

Comment: This is where i took the double line code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281862/drawing-a-double-line

Comment: Thanks! I posted an example how to change the colour, but I still have no idea what you might want to change about the cell alignment.

Comment: I have edited the code and filled in my actual code with the output. All 3 columns are not aligned with the same spacing.

Comment: Can you maybe draw some arrows where you want to change the alignment?

Comment: I have put in an image with the comments where I need help.

Comment: I added a new answer with the read line spanning the whole paper and the left and right column with the same width (although the right column will look smaller because it simply does not have any long text spanning the whole text width)

Comment: Thanks this works.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12 pt,a4 paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1in,right=1 in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{multirow}
\fancyhf{}
\newcommand{\doublerule}[1][.4pt]{%
  \noindent%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[.7ex]{\linewidth}{#1}}%
  \rule[.3ex]{\linewidth}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\vspace{12 mm}
\centerline{%
\makebox[\paperwidth]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{.08\paperwidth}} p{.32\paperwidth} p{.2\paperwidth} p{.32\paperwidth} @{\hspace{.08\paperwidth}} }
\multicolumn{1}{@{}r@{}}{\Large Bangalore} & \centering\multirow{1}{*}{\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-duck}} & \Large University\\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}r@{}}{\large Dr Vijaykumar H Doddamani} &   & Department of Physics\\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}r@{}}{M.Sc., M. Phil., PhD} && Ph. Off: 080-22961471/84 \\
&&Fax: 080-23219295\\
\textbf{\large Professor} & & Mobile : 9481300346 \\
Email: drvkd@gmail.com & \centering Jnanabharathi Campus  & Mobile : 9448673274 \\
\hphantom{Email:} profvijaykumarhd@bub.ernet.in & \centering Bengaluru - 560 056  & WhatsApp :9741716744 \\[2mm]
\arrayrulecolor{red}\hline\hline
\end{tabular}%
}}



\end{document}
```

[image]